# I can't delete files from trash in gksudo nautilus

Tags: nautilus, matlab, gksudo

I installed MATLAB in root. But when I try to delete it from gksudo nautilus I do not have access in trash. I tried via terminal but still I can't do it.

How can I delete these files?

Answer (score 0):

To delete your Matlab folder in `/`, use `sudo` to do the `rm` operation with superuser privileges:

```
$ sudo rm -fr /MATLAB
```

**Be cautious!** This command will remove `/MATLAB` directory without putting it into Trash. It will be removed without ability to restore.

If you could not run this command using `sudo` command because of your user is not in `sudo` group, then use the next command to add your user to this group:

```
# usermod -aG sudo <username>
```

You need to run this command as root.